# relative rank two group: structure of parabolic subgroup-- high-level Jacobson--Morozov sl_2 triple

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, langlands-conjectures

Given a parabolic subgroup $P=MN$ of a connected reductive group $G$ defined over a local field $F$, let $W_M$ be the relative Weyl group of $M$ in $G$, assume that the reduced roots relative to $M$ in $G$ form a root system of rank two, i.e. 
$$W_M=\left< S_\alpha, S_\beta \right>,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the simple roots of M in G, and $S_\alpha$ and $S_\beta$ are the corresponding simple reflections which satisfy
$$S_\alpha.M=M \mbox{ and } S_\beta.M=M.$$

For simple root $\alpha$ (resp. $\beta$), we denote by $M_\alpha$ (resp. $M_\beta$) the Levi subgroup of its associated maximal parabolic subgroup. Denote by $M'_\alpha$ the derived group of $M_\alpha$, similarly $M'_\beta$.

The question about high-level Jacobson--Morozov SL_2 triple is as follows:

at least one of $M'_\alpha$ and $M'_\beta$ is isogenous to $SL(n,D)$?

where $D$ is a division algebra over $F$.

If $G$ is quasi-split and $P$ is a minimal parabolic subgroup, then it is isogenous to $Res_{E/F}SL_2$ or $SU(2,1)_{F(\sqrt{d})/F}$.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you consider ${\mathbb R}$ as a local field, this is wrong for the Tits index $E_{6,2}^{28}$ (both Levi subgroups are of type $D_5$ then). For finite extensions of p-adic numbers your claim seems to be true by case-by-case considerations (not much possibilities for relative rank $2$ groups).

Comment: Thanks! the relative root system is of type $A_1\times A_1$? If so, let us first exclude this situation.

Comment: Jacobson-Morozov?

Comment: Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: No, the relative root system is $A_2$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks! then let us just consider the p-adic local field case.